# Maximising the Area of a Cyclic Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, optimization, contest-math

In cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AB = AD$. If $AC = 6$ and $AB/BD = 3/5$, find the maximum possible value of $[ABCD]$.

*(Source: SMT 2014)*

If we let $AB=AD = 3x$ and $BD=5x$, from Ptolemy, we have $BC+CD=10$. From the triangle inequality, we can also get $BC+CD > BD \Rightarrow 10 > 5x \Rightarrow x < 2$. I'm stuck on where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I've been exposed to a solution to this problem.

Since $AB=AD$, $\angle ABD = \angle ADB$. Furthermore, from the proprerties of a cyclic quadrilateral, $\angle ACB = \angle ADB$ and $\angle ACD = \angle ABD$. Therefore, $\angle ACB = \angle ADB = \angle ABD = \angle ACD$. Most importantly, $\angle ACB = \angle ACD$. Note that the area of $ABCD$ is equal to the area of $ABC$ added to the area of $ADC$. We use the alternate area formula $\frac{1}2 ab \sin C$, as follows: (Note that we let $\angle ACB = \angle ADB = \angle ABD = \angle ACD = \alpha$)
 \begin{align*}\\&[ABCD] \\&= [ABC]+[ADC] \\&=\frac{1}2(AC)(BC)\sin\alpha+\frac{1}2(AC)(DC)\sin\alpha \\&=\frac{1}2(AC)\sin\alpha(BC+CD)\end{align*}

We are given $BC+CD = 10$ and $AC = 6$, so that $[ABCD] =\frac{1}2 (10)(6)(\sin \alpha) = 30 \sin \alpha$. Since $\alpha = \angle ADB$, we can compute the $\cos$ of $\alpha$ easily: drop the perpendicular from A to BD, and let X be the foot of that perpendicular. Note that $AXD$ is a right triangle with $DX = \frac{5}{2} x$, so $\cos \alpha = \frac{\frac{5}2}3 = \frac{5}6$. Therefore, since $\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1$ and $\sin \alpha$ is positive, $\sin \alpha = \sqrt{11}{6}$, and the answer is $\boxed{5\sqrt{11}}$. The area is the same no matter what.

[image: From the Art of Problem Solving Forums]

Thanks to the active members of the Art of Problem Solving Forums for posting this solution. Original link was [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3685925#p3685925). The problem was lovely.

Answer (score 0):

this is a hunch. i expect the maximum area to occur when the cyclic quadrilateral looks like a kite: the diagonals are orthogonal and the quad is symmetric about $AC$.

if you let $AB = AD = 3x, BD = 5x.$ let the diagonal $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $E, AE = y, EC = 6-y.$ we have two equations for $x, y$ they are: $$9x^2 = 25/4 x^2 + y^2, y(6-y) = 25/4 x^2.$$ with the solution  $$x = {2\sqrt{11} \over 6}, y = {11 \over 6} \mbox{ and maximum area =   } 5 \sqrt{11}.$$

Comment: You seem to have swapped $C$ and $D$. I have edited your answer to put them right; let me know if I have misread your intentions.

Comment: @TonyK, thanks for noticing the error. i will have to fix my answer.

Comment: How do you know the kite case is the greatest?

Comment: @JamesLi,  like i said in my answer, this is only a hunch. i need to justify it more rigorously. i will think about it more.